# Reload sequelize models without restarting express

Tags: express, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize with different databases. However, when I add another database into the postgres server, sequelize does not recognize that database until the express app is reloaded. The issue is that my routes cannot use a new database, until I reload the app.

In the routes sequelize is loaded like so:
`const databases = require('../../models');`
which is supposed to read the models/index.js file which loads the databases. However, the new database is not loaded

How can I add a database and use it in the routes, WITHOUT restarting the express app? Is there a place where the sequelize settings/connections are stored within the express session - can that be edited?

Comment: Models are registered in the Sequelize instance (i.e. in a connection to a certain DB). So to connect to another DB you need to create another Sequelize instance and register all models once again in it.

Comment: @Anatoly this is a multi tenancy app, so I need to add a db connection to the current Sequelize instance for a new tenant without restarting express. Do you know where the Sequelize instance is stored to edit it?

Comment: I don't see any connection between Sequelize and Express from your question. Maybe you need to add some more details to clarify this.

Comment: @Anatoly when my express app is running, I have a db connection for each tenant. The connections get read into the app in models/index.js   My question is, when you make a change and need to add another connection, how can I reprocess index.js without restarting the express app. Or how can I modify whatever sequelize creates (app variable?) in the index.js file in order to add a db connection

Comment: At least you should have a function that takes connection params and returns a Sequelize instance with all registered models. It's a bit confusing that you mix models and databases. A Sequelize instance is bound to a certain DB and has its own registered models each of which is linked to a certain table in the DB.

Comment: @Anatoly ahh, I am not using the models to write queries. We use sequelize for security and organization purposes (migrations etc). I do have a function like you say, but where do I fire it off and where do I store the connections - req?

Comment: It can vary and totally depends on you where to store it